# Can MPMoviePlayerController have volume programmatically adjusted?

Tags: mpmovieplayercontroller, core-audio, volume

I have this MPMovePlayerController and a custom slider (which is not quite a slider, but it has the same purpose). Considering that my "slider" can return any float value I need, how can I change the volume of the played movie?

So far I'v tried hacking MPVolumeView to programmatically set a value, w/o success.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### iOS 3.0 - 7.0

Turns out that

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:<insert float here>];
```

works for any sound in the app, even the MPMoviePlayerController, if it's using the main Audio Session. O, it works only on the device, not the simulator. More info here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmusicplayercontroller?language=objc

---

#### Update

Volume is deprecated in iOS 7.0.

> "*To provide UI for adjusting system playback volume, use the [`MPVolumeView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpvolumeview?language=objc) class, which provides media playback controls that iOS users expect and whose appearance you can customize.*" [Deprecated MPMusicPlayerController Volume Method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmusicplayercontroller/1624567-volume?language=objc)

Comment: Your solution does not make sense. You were asking for a volume setting on MPMoviePlayerController but you are posting a property of MPMusicPlayerController which MPMoviePlayerController does not inherit from.

Comment: I agree that at first look they are not related, but if the MPMoviePlayerController uses the shared audio session, the MPMusicPlayerController has volume control over it. I wasn't expecting this either.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This may actually be the superior option compared to my solution as it will not break that easily on future iOS updates.

Comment: Update: Volume is deprecated in iOS 7.0.  _"To provide UI for adjusting system playback volume, use the MPVolumeView class, which provides media playback controls that iOS users expect and whose appearance you can customize."_  [Deprecated MPMusicPlayerController Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MPMusicPlayerController/volume)

Answer (score -1):

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:<insert float here>];
```

Will change the device's volume, not the media player's so any other audio or video streams are also affected.

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer, since it's the same answer as Tudorizer's..